# How to receive a set<String> returned by java method in C++ JNI, can we Convert jobject to set<String>?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am calling an instance method of Java class from C++ using JNI.
My Java's method return set and I need to catch this in C++.Can someone please help?

My Java method look like below.

```
@Override
public Set<String> getRealmRights() 
{
     Set<String> realmRights = new HashSet<>();
     -----------------
     -----------------
     return realmRights;
}
```

I am invoking the method from C++ like below.

```
jmethodID getRealmRightsMethodId = env->GetMethodID(keycloakAdapterApplicationClassId, "getRealmRights", "()Ljava/util/Set;");
if(getRealmRightsMethodId != nullptr)
{
    jobject rights = (jobject ) env->CallObjectMethod(keycloakAdapterApplication, getRealmRightsMethodId);
    //@ this stage I want to read the information from jobject,Please help?
}
```

I am getting method id correctly and even able to execute the method.

I tried to type cast jobject in set but failed. Can I directly catch this in a set OR can i convert jobject into set ?

I want to print the information returned by java function.Please help?

Comment: What do you mean by _"catch this"_? A `Set` is not a `jarray`, it's a `jobject`. If you want to access the elements in the set you could e.g. use `toArray` in your Java code to return a `String[]` instead of a `Set<String>`. If for some reason you can't change the Java code you can do the same from C++ (`GetObjectClass`, `GetMethodID`, `CallObjectMethod`, etc).

Comment: I received the information in jobject,Could you please tell me how i can read it?  jobject is holding the value of type Set<String>.

Comment: You would use the functions I mentioned to get a reference to the `Set` class, the ID of the method in `Set` that you want to call (e.g. `toArray`), and then you'd call that method. Once you've got a `jobjectArray` you'd process it as usual. This is all standard JNI programming (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html), so it's unclear exactly what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access `Set` class methods and retrieve objects stored inside collection.

I don't have out of the box sample for sets, but it will be very similar to code that you can find here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo037

What you need to do, is to get methods from `Set` object using `GetMethodID` and then, call them.

This way, you can descent to data stored inside `Set`. In your case, you have to:

- call method `GetMethodID` (and pass `Set` object into it) to get `Iterator` from `Set`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator()

- call method `GetMethodID` for object of class `Iterator` so you can get two methods: `hasNext` and `next`
- then, you have to iterate over `Set` using the Iterator and retrieve elements one by one (they will be of `jobject`s type)

You can also take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo042

```
  /* Get objarg's class - objarg is the one we pass from
     Java */
  jclass clsSet = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, objarg);

  /* Use javap to get propper descriptor
     > javap -s -p java.util.Set | grep -A 1 toArray
         public abstract java.lang.Object[] toArray();
           descriptor: ()[Ljava/lang/Object;
  */

  jmethodID midToArray =
    (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clsSet, "toArray", "()[Ljava/lang/Object;");

  /* We have to make sure that method exists */
  if (midToArray == NULL) {
    return -1; /* method not found */
  }

  /* Once we have method, we can call "toArray" and this way
     get array of all keys */
  jobjectArray arrayOfElements = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, objarg, midToArray);

  /* We will iterate over the array so we can get value for each key */
  int arraySize = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arrayOfElements);

  /* We want to go over all elements (all keys) */
  for (int i=0; i < arraySize; i++)
  {
    /* First, we need to get key value from array of all keys */
    jstring obj = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, arrayOfElements, i);
    const char* c_string = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, obj, 0);

    /* We can print values passed to C from Java */
    printf("[value] = [%s]\n", c_string);

    /* Make sure to release local stuff */
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, obj, c_string);

  }
```